# Correct use of ZMQ publisher in my project

Tags: c++, zeromq

I've been able to write and run simple ZMQ publisher-subscriber examples but now need to integrate them into a larger project and ran into a deadlock.

My `main()` function has a callback that is executed very often. Inside the callback, a certain class is instantiated and its member function called. This member function is the one that does something and publishes some data. I need to know where to prepare the ZMQ context, publisher sockets and bind the socket for best performance. If I do all these inside the member function, its not optimal since it will be called so often and they just need to be done once.

```
int main(){
    // Set up callback to mycallback()
}

void mycallback(args){
    Class cls;
    cls.somefunction();
}

// from Class.cpp
void Class::somefunction(){
     // Publish
     char msg[20];
     sprintf (msg, "Test");
     s_send(publisher, msg);
}
```

How and where should I put the lines?:

```
   zmq::context_T context(1);
   zmq::socket_t publisher(context, ZMQ_PUB);
   publisher.bind("tcp://*:5556");
```

Comment: Can't you just create the context in main function and pass the reference to it to your callback ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the callback argument format is fixed

Comment: How about using a singleton which stores the context ? Don't say it was me who suggested singleton ;)

Comment: My knowledge of C++ does not reach up to singletons. Will read about it and get back

Comment: You probably want to create a single context_t in main and pass it in to the `Class` constructor, which then creates and stores a local publisher socket.

Comment: @David, Yes that is one way I considered but the constructor will be called every time the callback is invoked and so the socket will be created multiple times. The manual for ZMQ says that a socket should be created just once.

Comment: Is using thread_local static in the member function for creating the context and socket a possible solution?